# speed up css keyframe animation over duration of time

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a keyframe infinite loop that spins a circle around and looks like a loading element. My goal is two things:

1. Set the animation to last X amount of seconds and
2. Increase the speed at which the circle spins as it gets closer to reaching X

   ```
     <style>
     @keyframes spinner {
         to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
     }

     @-webkit-keyframes spinner {
         to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
     }

     .spinner {
         min-width: 30px;
         min-height: 30px;
     }

     .spinner:before {
         content: 'Loading…';
         position: absolute;
         top: 50%;
         left: 50%;
         width: 24px;
         height: 24px;
         margin-top: -13px;
         margin-left: -13px;
     }

     .spinner:not(:required):before {
         content: '';
         border-radius: 50%;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         border-top-color: red;
         animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
         -webkit-animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
     }
     </style>

     <div class="spinner"></div>
   ```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cLq2v72o/